# Java Generics List and ArrayList with and without Parameters

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

I'm reading about Java Generics. and I want to ask what is the difference between the following statements.

1: `List<String> list = new ArrayList(3);`

2: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(2);`

3: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`

4a: `List<String> list = new ArrayList("A");` // why I can't use String?

4b: `List<String> list = new ArrayList('a');` // but char works fine.

I'm reading [Java Docs on Generics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) and after that I need to ask the above questions because I didn't get exact answer.(May be due to poor English)

Comment: `char` isn't working fine, it is being treated as an `int`. a good place to start is reading the [javadoc for ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Comment: @SeanBright ArrayList can just take int as parameter? if yes then what is the working of that parameter?

Comment: the documentation i linked to explains that

Comment: @SeanBright I'm reading docs here [A] (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html) what is the difference between both links? your and mine? any updated version difference?

Comment: my link points specifically to the documentation of `ArrayList` where you can read about the various constructor arguments.

Comment: @LetDoit Sean's link is the official Java documentation (called JavaDocs) - whatever it says here is how the language works. It goes into a lot of detail about method overloads, parameters, class hierarchy, etc... Your link, on the other hand, is part of the (official) tutorial, which is typically good enough for beginners but doesn't have as much detail as the documentation.

Comment: @NikG I was expecting these are official Documents and already read allllot. Now I should move to Sean's link.

Comment: @LetDoit The JavaDocs are a bit dry to read if you're trying to learn programming in general. I think it's okay if you stick with the tutorials for now and go to the JavaDoc when you have more specific questions like this one.

Comment: @NikG nice suggestion.. Thanks.

Comment: @NikG I think Sean's link is about javase7 can you confirm me javase8 docs link? is it? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/

Comment: @LetDoit You are correct, that is for the Java 8.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has nothing to do with generics. `ArrayList` has a constructor that takes an `int`, which represents the initial capacity of the List. A `char` (`'a'`) is convertible to `int`, which is why 4b works just like 1 and 2. There's no constructor that takes a `String`, so 4a doesn't pass compilation.

EDIT:

Instantiating a class using a raw type (i.e. without a type parameter, as in `List<String> list = new ArrayList(3)`), is something you shouldn't do, as it is less type safe, and is only allowed for backwards compatibility.

Comment: Well, that's explaining 4a... the difference between 1 and 2 *does* have do do with generics...

Comment: @Eran when I use String as type argument as in option 2 or 3. `new ArrayList<String>();` then why Compiler notify me for Diamond operator? `<>` ?

Comment: @LetDoit The diamond operator is a shortcut that lets you type less code. Instead of writing `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(2);`, you can write the equivalent `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(2);`.

Comment: @Eran ok the second as you says in your first line, `which represents the initial capacity of the List.` when I use `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(1);` and use `list.add("a");` more than 2 time then why it's not show me index out of bound or extra adding error?

Comment: @LetDoit The number you specify is just the initial capacity. The capacity increases automatically whenever the current capacity is not enough to hold all the elements of the List. Unlike arrays, the size of an ArrayList is not bound.

Comment: @Eran then passing `int` as argument is useless?

Comment: @Let Do it No, it can improve performance. If you know in advance that your list will contain at least 100000 elements, you can use 100000 as the initial capacity and save the time it would take the capacity to grow automatically as you add elements to the list.

Answer (score 0):

The [ArrayList constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(int)) you're using has nothing to do with the generic type. It simply takes an `int` signifying its initial capacity.

When you call `new ArrayList('a')`, you're simply promoting `'a'` to an `int` (65).

Comment: Why everyone repeating answer of 4th option?

Comment: same the Sean's link you also gave me javase7 link why not 8?