# How to give a List of any object as parameter in Java?

Tags: java, list, generics, inheritance

I have several classes that are doing the same thing : iterates over a List in an object, and add each items in a private field.
I have two objects : MyCustomObject, that have several fields, and ResultOfQuery, where it has a field called data that is a `List<Map<String, Object>>`.

**For example**:

```
private List<MyCustomObject> myCustomObjectList = new LinkedList();

public void setMyCustomObject (ResultOfQuery resultOfQuery){
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    if(resultOfQuery!= null) {
        for (Map<String, Object> map : resultOfQuery.getData()) {
            myCustomObjectList.add(objectMapper.convertValue(map, 
                    MyCustomObject.class));
        }
    }
```

The problem is that I have other classes that does the exact same method, but with another object instead of MyCustomObject.

So I thought that a good idea would be that all of these classes should extends a class that contains this method, and as a parameter it should take first a resultOfQuery, then a list of any objects, and then a Class.
Does it sounds good, or there is a better way to achieve this?

Also, how to give a list of any object ? I tried `List<?>`, but this shows me the following error :

[Error at list add line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3748c.png)

Comment: Did you consider using `Java Generics`?

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve type safety with generics and inheritance. If you declare a base class having the common stuff like:

```
public class BaseClass<T> {
    
    private List<T> tList = new LinkedList<>();
    private final Class<T> classT;
    
    public BaseClass(Class<T> classT) {
        this.classT = classT;
    }
    
    public void setObject (ResultOfQuery resultOfQuery){
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        if(resultOfQuery!= null) {
            for (Map<String, Object> map : resultOfQuery.getData()) {
                tList.add(objectMapper.convertValue(map, classT));
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Then it is easy to extend it for each different type, like:

```
public class MyCustomObjectExtendedClass extends BaseClass<MyCustomObject> {
    public MyCustomObjectExtendedClass() {
        super(MyCustomObject.class);
    }
}
```

I have renamed stuff because it was decoupled from the `MyCustomObject`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `private List myCustomObjectList = new LinkedList();`

Instantiating a class using a raw type (i.e. without a type parameter, as in List list = new ArrayList(3)), is something you shouldn't do, as it is less type-safe, and is only allowed for backwards compatibility.

Link: [Java Generics List and ArrayList with and without Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32783401/java-generics-list-and-arraylist-with-and-without-parameters)

Comment: Thanks a lot for these informations! The only problem is I tried to implement it, but on the line myCustomObjectList.add, I have the following warning "unchecked call to add(E) as a member of the raw type java.util.List". Is it the best way to do it? I don't really want to put a @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")

Comment: I think @SuppressWarnings is the best way. IDEA trying to say that you're doing smth wrong, it's ok :D